Safari (IOS) don't play audio (html5) stream
Safari browser on IOS doesn't play my audio stream, while other browsers like chrome/firefox all play fine.
I have an audio stream on site B which i wanted to play on site A, so i have the following code on site A:
<audio id="audio" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="none" controls="true" src="https://mysiteB.com:8058/stream" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
On safari i get the following fault:\

Failed to load resource: Cross-origin redirection to https://mysiteB.com:8058/stream?_ic2=1735037099039 denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin https://www.mysiteA.nl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 302

Is it because safari redirect to: ?_ic2=1735037099039   ?
MysiteB.com has the correct cors headers as far as i know, and the other browsers dont have the redirect to?_ic2... and are working fine.
When i use a third party audio player, the stream does play on safari.
tried different  codes but none of them are working

Please provide output of curl -IL https://.....
